# Computing cache miss rate

Tags: probability, computer-science

Consider a discrete-time random process X(t) taking values {1,2,...,n} for integer n>1.  For all times s not t, X(s) and X(t) are independent.

Let $p_k=P(X(t)=k)$, meaning X is stationary.

**(a)** Find the probability that $X(t+1)$ is not equal to $X(s)$ for any interval {t-T+1, t-T+2,...,t} of length T>1.

**(b)** Find the expected number of different values of X in this interval.

**(c)** Consider a cache that keeps track of the last B>1 different values of X.  Considering (a) and (b), find an approximate expression for the *miss rate* of the cache.

*I am stuck on part b and c.*

**For part a,** I want to compute the probability that

$$P[X(t+1)\ne X(t-T+1)]\cap P[X(t+1)\ne X(t-T+2)]\cap\cdots \cap P[X(t+1)\ne X(t)]$$

I start this by defining the conditional probability:

$$P[(X(t-T+1)\neq X(t+1)) \cap \cdots \cap (X(t)\neq X(t+1)) \mid X(t+1)=n]$$

Since the prior is independent of X(t-T+1) for all t, these can be split into:

$$P[X(t-T+1)\neq X(t+1)\mid X(t+1)=n]  \cdots  P[X(t)\neq X(t+1)\mid X(t+1)=n] $$

which is equal to:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{N}(1-p_k)^Tp_k$$

I am pretty confident this is correct.  Now for part b....

For part b, I have to find the expected number of different values of X in this interval.  My thought is to approach this problem as computing the number of unique values of set {1,2,3,...,n} which can fill the interval of size T where T>1.  I think this is equivalant to saying if you choose T items from n *with* replacement modulated by the probabilities $p_k$, what is the number of expected unique items you will have.

Suppose $T=2$ and I want compute part b.  For the first slot, I have $p_k$ probability of the first item.  For the second slot, I have a probability $1-p_k$ of it not being item k. I am stumped at this point.

Comment: This looks like an assignment that has been carefully copied to Math.SE.  Help Readers to understand the purpose of your Question by adding more context.

Comment: Fixed.  I am overall very stumped on this question but posted what i have written so far.

Comment: I know that seems awkward, but it greatly improves the Question.  Thanks.

Comment: Its really no problem.  I didnt think anyone would care about my poor attempt.